# Half-integer Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose we want to carry out the (generalized) Fourier transform of a function defined in the domain $\mathbb{T}\times\tfrac12\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. dependent on the arguments $\phi\in\left(-\pi,+\pi\right]$ (or other $2\pi$ length interval) and $\psi\in\tfrac12\mathbb{Z}=\pm\left\{0,\tfrac12,1,\tfrac32,\dots\right\}$. A suitable $\phi$ transform is a Fourier series, and a suitable $\psi$ transform is a Fourier sequence transform or discrete-time Fourier transform. I have doubts about the latter.

The thing is $\psi\in\tfrac12\mathbb{Z}$, not $\mathbb{Z}$ itself. I do not think it makes a big difference, but some issues may be spotted.

The first question is if it can be done just like this:
$$
\sum_{\psi\in\tfrac12\mathbb{Z}}{e^{-i\psi\psi'}f\left(\psi\right)}=\sum_{\psi\in\mathbb{Z}}{e^{-i\psi\psi'}f\left(\psi\right)}+\sum_{\psi\in\tfrac12\mathbb{Z}\backslash\mathbb{Z}}{e^{-i\psi\psi'}f\left(\psi\right)}=\sum_{\psi\in\mathbb{Z}}{e^{-i\psi\psi'}f\left(\psi\right)}+\sum_{\psi\in\mathbb{Z}}{e^{-i\left(\psi+\tfrac12\right)\psi'}f\left(\left(\psi+\tfrac12\right)\right)}
$$

The second question is how to understand this transformation with $e^{-i\left(\psi+\tfrac12\right)\psi'}$. I realize that this is not a very precise question, but I am looking forward to a bit more coverage of this issue. It certainly has something to do with the anti-periodic function. However, I have not enough imagination to determine whether $2\pi$ is an (actual) period of this function or just a "period" of its anti-periodicity (half of the actual one).

The third question concerns the inverse transformation (with respect to $\psi'$). Whether $\psi'$ will belong to $\mathbb{T}\simeq\left(-\pi,+\pi\right]$ or instead to an interval of a different length. And whether the reverse transformation should be performed with a period of $2\pi$ or some other length.

$$
\int_{\mathbb{T}}{\frac{d\psi'}{2\pi}e^{i\psi'\psi}\hat{f}\left(\psi'\right)}
$$

Generally, I look for a comprehensive introduction to harmonic analysis (Fourier-type transformations) in the case of anti-periodic functions.

I would be grateful for any answers, clarification, or expansion of these topics.

This question was [originally posted on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115952/half-integer-fourier-transform), but to date without any answer.

Comment: Change every occurrence of $\psi$ to $\psi/2$, and suddenly your function is on $\mathbb T \times \mathbb Z$.  This seems like a purely notational problem; what's the subtlety?